# Fetching 'https' pages using 'urlopen' vs getpage()

Tags: python, twisted, urlopen

I'm trying to get an 'https' webpage(for eg: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap) using urlopen(), it returns the page without any problem. But we are evaluating Twisted for a new project and trying to use getPage() to fetch the same page. But seems it requires openSSL module.. `"exceptions.ImportError: No module named OpenSSL"`

Is there any way to get on with getPage() (without openSSL module) to get an 'https' page the same way urlopen() returns ?

Comment: That `s` after the `http` means you need SSL support from _somewhere_.

Comment: Yes, it should use SSL from somewhere. There is SSL handshakes happening as I can see from WireShark. It seems urlopen uses built-in SSL (httplib.HTTPS). But how does it handles certificates ? I can see the certificates are empty to the HTTPS __init__().

Answer (score 2):

Why not just [install pyOpenSSL](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyOpenSSL)?

Comment: I'm writing a module which needs to be distributed to users, and I would like to minimize external dependencies as possible as I can.

Comment: So minimize them.  You can distribute pyOpenSSL with your project, too.  Just because it's a dependency doesn't mean it's an *external* dependency.  This kind of dependency minimization is a waste of time and effort.